# How to output a row from table and insert all the row data in the option tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new in programing and i have stuck in one piece.
Well I have 1 database, in that database I have some teams, my goal is to put those teams in a option tag where I can modify the team. Thanks all!

```
$sql_grupi = "select grup_name from grupi";
    $res_grupi = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql_grupi);
    $res_array = array();

    if (!$res_grupi) {
        die("Error");
    } 


    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_grupi, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $res_array[] = $row['grup_name'];

    }
```

---

### down here is my form where i call the table data

```
<select name="grupi">
    <option value="<?php $res_array; ?>"><?php $res_array; ?></option>
</select>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking? Are you trying to make a select with all your teams as options?

Comment: Yes this is my goal. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it through loop array:

```
echo '<select name="grupi">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res_grupi, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "<option value='".$row['grup_id']."'>".$row['grup_name']."</option>"
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gouda!! . Now my only problem is that i can't insert the selected value to database. I get a error in my query

Comment: my query is this --> $insert = "update users set fname='$fname', lname='$lname', usr='$dbusr', psw='$dbpsw', position='$position', grupi='THIS IS THE ERROR', atesia='$atesia', id_carta='$id_carta', tel='$tel', email='$email', adresa='$adresa' where usr='$getusr' ";

Comment: How to declare my selected option to query?

Comment: you need to read firstly @Rafael, try to google form POST, GET, and how to read form inputs through $_POST array, also try to read about mysqli

Comment: Thank you very much Gouda you are the best!! You have really help me :)